# Nautilus script not showing up in right click menu when nothing is selected

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, nautilus

I have the following script to add an action to my right click menu in Nautilus (using Ubuntu 20.04):

`~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open with Disk Usage Analyzer`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS" ]; then
    set $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        destination="$1"
        if [ ! -d "$destination" ]; then
            destination="$(dirname "$destination")"
        fi
    else
        zenity --error --title="Error - Open with Disk Usage Analyzer" --text="You can only select one directory."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    destination="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
fi

baobab "$destination"
```

The script appears properly in the right click menu when a folder (or file) is selected:

[image]

However, if no files or folders are selected, the Scripts entry does not appear at all in the right click menu:

[image]

How do I get the Scripts entry to appear in the right click menu regardless of whether a selection is made or not?

Comment: already answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672730/scripts-menu-not-showing-up-while-right-clicking-an-empty-area)

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus has always been like this, I used Pcman-FM, I migrated to Nautilus in 2009, and it has always been that way, unfortunately, you have to select a folder to have the script. It's better to use fff or ranger :)